# QTableWidget insertRow for values incoming in different time

Tags: qt, sockets, insert, row, qtablewidget

I have an application which contains 10 `QTCPSocket` and all the time the sockets are receiving values from server. Values are received at different times. I want to store values in `QTableWidget` but I don't know when to call `insertRow()`. I try and add a row at the first socket update, but when the second socket data is received before the first it doesn't work.

I insert new row in first socket by:

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
addItemToTable(0, value);
```

and the addItemToTable method:

```
void MainWindow::addItemToTable(int columnNumber, int value)
 {
     QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(value));
     ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, columnNumber, newItem);
 }
```

This is the method for reading the socket data

```
void SocketManager::readData(QTcpSocket *socket) 
{ 
 QString str = socket->readAll(); int result = int(str.at(0).toLatin1());
 emit sendValue(result);
 }
```

Comment: Show the code where you receive data on the socket.

Comment: `void SocketManager::readData(QTcpSocket *socket)
{
    QString str = socket->readAll();
    int result = int(str.at(0).toLatin1());
    emit sendValue(result);
}`

Comment: You're assuming that `readData` will receive any particular amount of data. That's wrong. `readData` can receive as little as one byte at a time.

Comment: I found that example in network and I use it in my app. I should use read() ?

Comment: No. You should not assume that `readAll` will return a full number. How are the numbers separated? By line endings? If so, then you should check that you've got a full line first (`socket->canReadLine()`) and only then attempt to extract anything from it. Otherwise, you should go through the received data to check for any other packet boundaries (say, spaces), and only then extract one or more numbers from it, and finally move the tail part of the packet back into the front of your buffer.

Comment: And I don't think that you found an example exactly like that. `readAll()` is something you must use, but the rest of your code is wrong.

Comment: but it work in that  way : i send request and received one number. On one message sent to server i received one full number(integer).

Comment: Just because it works sometimes doesn't mean it will work in all circumstances. The underlying protocol (TCP/IP) makes absolutely no guarantees as to how the data is chunked, and the operating system on the receiving end makes no such guarantees either. If you will keep doing it that way, you'll ship broken code. You don't have to trust me on this, simply point to a standard or spec that **substantiates the way you use the TCP/IP protocol**. You're relying on a behavior that's coincidential. Your code is brittle. Don't do that.